# Downloaded data is quote-driven or order-driven?

Tags: market-data, market-microstructure, bloomberg, market-making, limit-order-book

I downloaded data from **Refinitiv Datastream** (But I think that you get the same data from **Bloomberg**) to write my thesis. I downloaded prices and volumes.

I have a crucial question now: Are the prices that I downloaded from Refinitiv *(Closing price of day t)* **quote-** or **order-** driven prices?
That is, are they the quotes set by the market maker or the limit order price set by another trader?

PS. Volumes are just for continuous trading or also opening and closing auctions?

Comment: You should specify which market(s) you're looking at.